# What is the type of this differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Hello guys i am computer engineering student and  i am taking differential equations class and our teacher had asked two questions question in final exam but i have never seen that type of differential equation in my life.

This is the first question , he said find the general solution of differential equation

[Dif Eq question 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApNsE.png)

$(D^4+8D^2+16)[y] =0$

and this is the second question that he asked and he said find the general solution of differential equation

[Dif Eq question 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5dvG.png)

$(D^2-3D+2)[y] = \frac {1}{1+e^-x}$

Can anyone help me guys , i really need to learn what is this and how to solve that type of differential equations. I hope i have explained my question well.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Is it the 'D' notation that's bothering you?

Comment: @Moo thank you.

Comment: @B.Goddard yes sir , i have prepared  for the final exam but i've not seen  that notation before , first time i saw that questions in the exam i shocked but now i'm preparing for second exam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $D^n$ just refers to the $n'th$ derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$.

So the first equation is just: $$y''''+8y''+16y=0$$

Which is a linear homogenous ordinary differential equation. To solve this let $y=e^{\gamma x}$ and you'll be left with a quadratic characteristic equation if you can't solve that drop a comment or do some research on 'linear homogenous ODE's'.

Similarly, the second equation is going to be: $$y''-3y'+2y=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$$

which is a linear nonhomogeneous ordinary differential equation. Solved almost exactly the same way however in this case, you will also have to find a particular solution (due to the inhomogeneity). Without having solved it yet myself, I would say to use the variation of parameters method to solve the particular solution.

Hope that answers your question!

Comment: it helped a lot thank you for your answer.

Comment: @op in addition you can notice that the expression with $D$ gives you directly the characteristic equation for finding the $\gamma$.